# I need help organizing and setting up textures and shaders on my mesh, how do I know which texture map is which?

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv, shaders

I am new to blender and texturing, basically new at everything. I have been trying to understand these concepts in a practical way. So I downloaded a head mesh and its texture maps but I really don't understand how to use each map and identifying which is which.

I tried to plug the shaders as best as I could but I still think there is something wrong.

[image: I have no idea how to use this one, it ends with ml]

[image: This one says mask]

[image: This one ends with n, I believe it is a Normal, but I have no clue]

[image: This one ends with o]

[image: Finally this one ends with t]

[Blender file with textures packed in](https://mega.nz/file/FM9DHaiC#PEwU8gx5ZN8ZA2sKhiOKRjnIfhg4unIeoZ-6TSiqS9A)

I would greatly appreciate your help!

The reason I separated the second texture map into RBG is because I read it was channel packed and I didn´t know how to use it any other way. I still don't know where to plug the other texture maps

Comment: I'd love to help, but you didn't include your textures in the blend, so I don't know what each one is doing. Go to `File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend`, and then upload again. Consider using this site's uploader - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Did as you asked me to. I couldn't get the file uploaded into that website, so I reuploaded it into MEGA. I truly tried but it never loaded.

Comment: We can expect each type of non-color data to be assigned to a single channel: R,G,B, & A where alpha is applicable (transparent PNG for example). It appears the relevant channels for the first two images that use a range of cyan and sea-green hues will be G & B. The 3rd image is pink, which uses all three color channels (RGB), yet it is not a diffuse map - so I'm guessing it's for SSS. The 4th image uses R & G channels, and we can see shadows behind the ears and in the nostrils that indicate the R channel is likely an AO map. The G channel could be a glossy map (invert for a roughness map).

Comment: I state these guesses without having opened the file (can't at the moment), and without having really analyzed Christopher Bennett's node setup. But maybe my guesses will provide you with some insight. Also, after hovering the macOS Digital Color Meter over the images, I see that surprisingly the first 2 images have R channel data as well, although I have no idea what for, or if it's even intentional. It's actually obvious once we notice that image 2 contains gray (in an RGB image, all three channels are required to represent white or any shade of gray).

Answer (score 0):

Here, try a setup like this. I think this is closer to what you're looking for (although I don't know what the end result is *supposed* to look like).

[image: Setup]

The texture you're using for your "normal map" seems to have most of (if not all) the useful information in the red channel, thus that's what I used. The data contained isn't sufficient for the use of a Normal Map node, but the B&W data can be used for a Bump Node.  I don't think I need the RGB to BW node, but I wanted to be sure for the bump to be as accurate as possible. As you can see, I had to soften it **greatly** by mixing it with white before it became anywhere close to realistic (unless the person in the model has really bad skin).

I took the same channel and inverted it to form the basis for the roughness, but had to mix it slightly with white to "even it out" - otherwise the face had distinct "oily-looking patches" that didn't quite match the sheen of a real face. Oh, and a face has no need for metallic values (unless there are piercings, glasses frames, chains, earrings, shrapnel, etc...), so I removed the input.

Lastly, I plugged the BaseColor (minus the Ambient Occlusion) into the Subsurface Color, and increased the strength a bit to make the model look less plastic. On the topic of Ambient Occlusion, don't forget you have to turn it on by checking the box in the render properties panel first, for it to have the proper effect.

This may not be perfect, but I hope it at least gets you closer.

NOTE - upon further inspection, the green channel of the second image texture seems to be an Ambient Occlusion map. You can either use it as color the input for the Ambient Occlusion Node, or just use the one we created from the heightmap (they are both very similar). The Blue channel contains pure black, so I assume it was meant for the Metallic input (0 value). You can connect it or just leave the input blank with the value at 0.

Comment: Thank you so much! I still don't quite understand which texture map is for what but you made it look so much better